# Python 2.7 : Can't figure out how to parse a tree with BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse [this site](http://mam.econoday.com/byweek.asp?day=7&month=4&year=2014&cust=mam&lid=0) to create 5 lists, one for each day and filled with one string for each announcement. For example

```
[in]   custom_function(page)

[out]  [[<MONDAYS    ANNOUNCEMENTS>],
        [<TUESDAYS   ANNOUNCEMENTS>],
        [<WEDNESDAYS ANNOUNCEMENTS>],
        [<THURSDAYS  ANNOUNCEMENTS>],
        [<FRIDAYS    ANNOUNCEMENTS>]]
```

But I can't figure out the correct way to do this.

This is what I have so far

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import datetime

url = http://mam.econoday.com/byweek.asp?day=7&month=4&year=2014&cust=mam&lid=0




# Get the text of the webpage
r               = requests.get(url)
data            = r.text
soup            = BeautifulSoup(data)


full_table_1 = soup.find('table', 'eventstable')
```

[image: ScreenShot of Website Developers Tools]

I Figured out that what I want is in the highlighted  tag, but I'm not sure how to get to that exact tag and then parse out the times/announcements into a list. I've tried multiple methods but it just keeps getting messier.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to find all `td` elements with `events` class, then read `div` elements inside:

```
data = []
for day in soup.find_all('td', class_='events'):
    data.append([div.text for div in day.find_all('div', class_='econoevents')])

print data
```

prints:

```
[[u'Gallup US Consumer Spending Measure8:30 AM\xa0ET',
  u'4-Week Bill Announcement11:00 AM\xa0ET',
  u'3-Month Bill Auction11:30 AM\xa0ET',
  ...
 ],
 ...
]
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work. It doesn't give me all the announcements of the day, only the announcements before the speakers. For example, on Monday the speaker is John Bullard, and I get all the announcements before he speaks, but not after he speaks.

Comment: @user1367204 well, I see, for example, `TD Ameritrade IMX` in the output - it's after the `John Bullard` in the Monday's list. What is the problem?

Comment: I don't have it for some reason. I don't even have John Bullard. I am using bs4 version 4.3.2.........[ScreenShot](http://i.imgur.com/JXInstw.png).....

Comment: @user1367204 I understand why there is no `John Bullard` - it's in a different block - span with the class `econoarticles`. We could get it too, but first we need to understand why you don't see `TD Ameritrade IMX`. Could you please try to initialize `BeautifulSoup` this way: `soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html5lib')` (you need to have `html5lib` module installed). Thanks.

Comment: Wow, that worked! I just need to add the 'html5lib' parameter. Thank you!